# Inner join using Django router

Tags: sql, django

I have two models "Users" and "UserHasMachine" which are connected by primary key
I wanted to create queryset with fields from both of the tables filtered by a field "machine" field in "UserHasMachine" table

I tried to use select_releated but it seems to return just full "User" table without filtering by a field in "UserHasMachine"

models.py

```py
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=128)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    pwd_hash = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    pwd_salt = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    is_builtin = models.IntegerField()
    has_account = models.IntegerField()
    is_verified = models.IntegerField()
    is_enabled = models.IntegerField()
    verifycode = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    user_creator = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING)
    is_deleted = models.IntegerField()
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'


class UserHasMachine(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, models.DO_NOTHING)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_has_machine'
        unique_together = (('user', 'machine'),)
```

views.py

```py
class UserMachineViewSet(ListRetrieveUpdateModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserHasMachine.objects.select_related('user')
    serializer_class = UserMachineSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = ('machine_id', )
    permission_classes = (partial(UserInAnyGroup, {
        'update': ['admin'],
        'partial_update': ['admin']
    }),)


class UserViewSet(ListRetrieveUpdateModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = ('id', )
    permission_classes = (partial(UserInAnyGroup, {
        'update': ['admin'],
        'partial_update': ['admin']
    }),)
```

serializers.py

```py
class UserMachineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserHasMachine
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = (
            'user',
            'machine',
            'role',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at'
        )


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = (
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at'
        )
```

I expect to return a queryset containing name and the email from "User" table filtered by the machine field in the "UserHasMachines" 
Here is the response I get then I call UserMachineViewSet:

```
...
{"JSON":[{"user":13,"role":"user","created_at":"2018-01-29T12:02:35","updated_at":"2018-01-29T12:02:35","machine":7},{"user":14,"role":"admin","created_at":"2018-01-29T12:02:35","updated_at":"2018-01-29T12:02:35","machine":7},{"user":39,"role":"user","created_at":"2018-10-02T13:39:12","updated_at":"2018-10-02T13:39:12","machine":7},
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misconception regarding `select_related`. All it does is to load user data from database when you are querying, so that you don't have to hit the database when accessing user information. For example:

```
queryset = UserHasMachine.objects.select_related('user')

for q in queryset:
    q.user  # will not hit database


queryset = UserHasMachine.objects.all()

for q in queryset:
    q.user  # will hit database
```

Now, if you want to show the user information in API, just add [**`depth=1`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) in serializer meta class:

```
class UserMachineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserHasMachine
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = (
            'user',
            'machine',
            'role',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at'
        )
        depth = 1
```

Then it will show nested fields inside user field.

BTW I am not clear about what you meant by:

> I expect to return a queryset containing name and the email from "User" table filtered by the machine field in the "UserHasMachines"

But the User information is already there in the queryset, and you can access it via:

```
# method 1

queryset = UserHasMachine.objects.select_related('user')

for q in queryset:
    print(q.user.id)

# method 2

queryset.values('user__id', 'user__email')

# method 3
# you can annotate any value of user with queryset like this:

from django.db.models import F

queryset = queryset.annotate(user_email=F('user__email'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I send the request to the database from my frontend is returning only fields from "UserHasMachine" table. It filters it by machine field but does not include corresponding email and name fields from User table. I tried adding depth, but didn't change it.

Comment: those values should be inside `user` field. Can you please check the response or share the response with the question?

Comment: User field in UserHasMachine is a foreign key of id in User table